# Is there any size limitation of SQL result?

Tags: postgresql, azure

I am using Azure PostgreSQL, I have a lot of files saved as byeta datatype in a table. In my project, I will execute some SQL query to get these files.

Sometimes a query will involve multiple files so the result data size of SQL query will be large. My questions: is there has some data size limit of SQL result for one SQL query ? Should I do some limit here? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Bytea datatype will store 1 or 4 bytes plus the actual binary string in the table. Your question is not exactly clear, are you using Database Services for Postgres in Azure.  Are you concerned about the Cloud storage? Or are you concerned on the size of column values or do you want to limit the number of records in the sql query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit for the size of a result set in PostgreSQL.

However, many clients cache the whole result set in memory, which can easily lead to an out-of-memory condition on the client side.

There are ways around that:

- Use cursors and fetch the result row by row or in batches. That should work with any client API.
- With the C API (libpq), you could activate single-row mode.
- With JDBC, you could set the fetch size.

Note that this means that you could get a runtime error from the database server in the middle of processing a result set.

Comment: laurenz-albe every PostgresSQL question is answered by you. Machine! Thank you! :pray:.